# How to represent an Airline's Lounge via Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

I could find [`Airport`](https://schema.org/Airport) and a property [`amenityFeature`](https://schema.org/amenityFeature) in [Schema.org](https://schema.org/). I need to find a way to represent a **Lounge** that belongs to an [`Airline`](https://schema.org/Airline).

How to find a Lounge that belongs to `Airline` on an `Airport`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent the lounge with [`LocalBusiness`](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness).

You can use the [`containedInPlace`](https://schema.org/containedInPlace) property to state that this `LocalBusiness` is part of the `Airport`.

You can use [`department`](https://schema.org/department)/[`parentOrganization`](https://schema.org/parentOrganization)/[`subOrganization`](https://schema.org/subOrganization) to state that the `LocalBusiness` belongs to the `Airline`.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use [LodgingBusiness](https://schema.org/LodgingBusiness) instead of [LocalBusiness] (https://schema.org/LocalBusiness)?

Comment: @4run4: I would say a lounge is not a [lodging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodging) business, because (as far as I understand) these seem to imply that you can sleep/live there.